# 'Unable to resolve module warnOnce' after following simple steps to run react-native application

Tags: android, react-native

Steps used are

1) create-react-native-app testApp

successfully created testApp directory.

2) inside android folder adding local.properties= {path to sdk}

3) now it says to run 'cd testApp' and 'npm run android'

4) after executing above steps successfully app-debug.apk is successfully installed on my connected device.

5) after launching testApp on my mobile it says below error.

[image]

6)Then searching for some link I got [solved-unable-to load-script](https://medium.com/@adityasingh_32512/solved-unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-bdc5e3a3d5ff)

7) after following it steps taken like creating assets directory 'android/app/src/main/assets' and running cmd 'react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest'

error: Unable to resolve module `warnOnce` from `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js`: warnOnce could not be found within the project.

I am stuck also I have followed some links on StackOverflow but still not able to proceed.

**Can somebody help me what to do next also are there any simpler steps to run this application on any android device easily?.**